# VBA Excel Graphing Add time to X-Axis

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I am graphing a trend for a pump for a day, I am getting a sample data every minuet

I got the graph all working but the problem I am running into is trying to get the time on the X-axis. There is a column that shows the time each sample data was taken, but when I tried to add it, it put the time for every point in the chart. Because I have 1440 points in the chart, it was just a blob of unreadable text, I removed that code and right now I am doing without. But I would like to figure it out.

```
    'Chart for Monday
    With wBM.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=300, Top:=10, Height:=300)
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=wBM.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B1440"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .Chart.ChartType = xlLine
    .Left = rngChart2.Left
    .Top = rngChart2.Top
    .Width = rngChart2.Width
    .Height = rngChart2.Height
    .Chart.HasTitle = True
    .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Monday " & Monday
    .Chart.HasLegend = False
    End With
```

This is my code so far. In Column D has the time for each point so it would be "D1:D1440".
Is there a way to only have 1 label for every 60 points, or 120? So that I don't have such a blob of labels?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with sample data that looks like this:

[image]

I ran this macro to hide all labels which 'location' is not multiple of 5

```
Sub formateDataLabels()
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Set chrt = ActiveChart

    Dim cnt As Long: cnt = 1

    For Each lbl In chrt.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
        If cnt Mod 5 <> 0 Then
            lbl.Text = ""
        End If

        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next lbl
End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image]

---

Note that the current code is simply set up to run on the selected chart. Change the 5 to whatever you need such as 50 or 100 and adapt to your current chart.